# How to install libusb-Win32 host driver into Windows IoT on Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, libusb, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I have a USB host C++ app running on Windows 10 that communicates by USB2 with an embedded USB device.

Now need to port to UWP C++ app on Windows IoT on Raspberry PI.

On my Windows 10, I first install the libusb-Win32 host driver into Windows.

Can't find how to do it in Windows IoT on Raspberry PI.

Comment: This need libusb-win32 driver for Windows IoT Core, ARM platform. Maybe building from [source](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/releases) is a way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of box driver of libusb for Windows IoT Core, ARM, but you can build from source to target ARM architecture.

[Source on GitHub](https://github.com/libusb/libusb).

If possible use modern USB API is easier.

Ref: "[How to connect to a USB device (UWP app)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/how-to-connect-to-a-usb-device--uwp-app-)".

Comment: The "Source on GitHub" link is bad.

Comment: @DougNull Sorry, I update it. The link I also mentioned in my previous comment.